# How to add rows with 0 counts to summarised output

Tags: r, count, dplyr, rows

I have added sample data below, I have used dplyr to count on `Rco` and `month`:

```
structure(list(Rco = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A220", "B334", "C123", "D445"
), class = "factor"), month = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Apr", "Feb", "Jan", 
"Mar"), class = "factor"), count = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 13)), .Names = c("Rco", "month", "count"), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Is there a way to transform this data to:

```
structure(list(Rco = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A220", "B334", 
"C123", "D445"), class = "factor"), month = structure(c(3L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("Apr", 
"Feb", "Jan", "Mar"), class = "factor"), count = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 10, 0, 13, 11, 12, 0)), .Names = c("Rco", "month", 
"count"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

So basically I need to add extra rows for all months that have missing count, because `dplyr::count` does not give 0 counts if a `month` - `Rco` combination does not exist.

The number of months is variable in my data ( I have shown Jan Feb Mar Apr but it could be for all 12 months as well) , so please if someone can provide me a dynamic solution, I would be grateful.

Comment: related Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451372/add-rows-to-grouped-data-with-dplyr

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tidyr::complete` and specify the fill to be 0 (instead of the default NA):

```
library(tidyr)
complete(df, Rco, month, fill = list(count = 0))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot docendo.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `expand.grid` on the `unique` values of the first two columns, and `merge` with the initial dataset.  This will fill `NA` for combinations that are not present in the `expand.grid`.

```
res <- merge(expand.grid(lapply(df1[1:2], unique)), df1, all.x=TRUE)
```

But, it is easy to change the `NA` to 0

```
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
```