# Inserting rows into data frame when values missing in category

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below. Note that on `day` `b`, there is no entry for `product` `1`. This indicates product 1 wasn't sold that day, but I want a row which makes this clear. That is, I want to add a row where `day=b`, `product=1`, and `sales=0`. I want to do this for each day-product pair that doesn't exist in the data frame, e.g. `day` `c` and `product` `3`. How can I accomplish this?

```
  df <- data.frame(day=c(rep('a',3), rep('b',2), rep('c',2)), 
                   product = c(1:3, 2:3,1:2), 
                   sales = runif(7))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 1

Thanks to @Frank for the better solution, using `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
complete(df, day, product, fill = list(sales = 0))
```

Using this approach, you no longer need to worry about selecting product names, etc.

Which gives you:

```
  day product      sales
1   a       1 0.52042809
2   b       1 0.00000000
3   c       1 0.46373882
4   a       2 0.11155348
5   b       2 0.04937618
6   c       2 0.26433153
7   a       3 0.69100939
8   b       3 0.90596172
9   c       3 0.00000000
```

---

## Option 2

You can do this using the `tidyr` package (and `dplyr`)

```
df %>% 
  spread(product, sales, fill = 0) %>% 
  gather(`1`:`3`, key = "product", value = "sales")
```

Which gives the same result

This works by using `spread` to create a wide data frame, with each product as its own column.  The argument `fill = 0` will cause all empty cells to be filled with a `0` (the default is `NA`).

Next, `gather` works to convert the 'wide' data frame back into the original 'long' data frame.  The first argument is the columns of the products (in this case `'1':'3'`).  We then set the `key` and `value` to the original column names.

I would suggestion option 1, but option 2 might still prove to have some use in certain circumstances.

---

Both options should work for all days you have at least one sale recorded.  If there are missing days, I suggest you look into the package `padr` and then using the above `tidyr` to do the rest.

Comment: Thanks. Here you specified the range of values for `product` manually. Is there a way to avoid this? In the real data there are hundreds of products, all defined by character values.

Comment: Sure thing, you could do this by calling through column number in the `gather` function (in the above case, you would use `2:4`).  You could also just list the first and last products as long as you use the semicolon (i.e. `product1:product100`).  If you don't have other columns besides the three you have here, you could also use `2:ncol(.)`

Comment: I think it should instead be `tidyr::complete(df, day, product, fill = list(sales = 0))` .

Answer (score 1):

If speed is a concern, a *self join to fill in missing levels* could be an option (see [section 3.5.5 of Frank's *Quick R Tutorial*](http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/tables.html#self-join-to-fill-in-missing-levels)):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[CJ(day = day, product = product, unique = TRUE), on = .(day, product)][
  is.na(sales), sales := 0.0][]
```

> ```
>    day product      sales
> 1:   a       1 0.57406950
> 2:   a       2 0.04390324
> 3:   a       3 0.63809278
> 4:   b       1 0.00000000
> 5:   b       2 0.01203568
> 6:   b       3 0.61310815
> 7:   c       1 0.19049274
> 8:   c       2 0.61758172
> 9:   c       3 0.00000000
> ```

#### Benchmark

Create benchmark data of 1 million rows minus 10% missing = 0.9 M rows:

```
n_day <-  1e3L
n_prod <- 1e3L
n_rows <- n_day * n_prod
# how many rows to remove?
n_miss <- n_rows / 10L
set.seed(1L)
df <- expand.grid(day = 1:n_day, product = 1:n_prod)
df$sales <- runif(n_rows)
#remove rows
df <- df[-sample.int(n_rows, n_miss), ]
str(df)
```

> ```
> 'data.frame': 900000 obs. of  3 variables:
>  $ day    : int  1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 11 12 ...
>  $ product: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ sales  : num  0.266 0.372 0.573 0.202 0.898 ...
>  - attr(*, "out.attrs")=List of 2
>   ..$ dim     : Named int  1000 1000
>   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "day" "product"
>   ..$ dimnames:List of 2
>   .. ..$ day    : chr  "day=   1" "day=   2" "day=   3" "day=   4" ...
>   .. ..$ product: chr  "product=   1" "product=   2" "product=   3" "product=   4" ...
> ```

Define check function:

```
my_check <- function(values) {
  all(sapply(values[-1], function(x) identical(as.data.frame(values[[1]]), as.data.frame(x))))
}
```

Run benchmarks:

```
library(data.table)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  tidyr = tidyr::complete(df, day, product, fill = list(sales = 0)),
  dt = setDT(df)[CJ(day = day, product = product, unique = TRUE), on = .(day, product)][
    is.na(sales), sales := 0.0][],
  times = 3L,
  check = my_check
)
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
>  tidyr 1253.3395 1258.0595 1323.5438 1262.7794 1358.6459 1454.5124     3   b
>     dt   94.4451  100.2952  155.4575  106.1452  185.9638  265.7823     3  a
> ```

For the given problem size of 1 M rows minus 10% missing, the `tidyr` solution is a magnitude slower than the `data.table` approach.

Comment: Thanks for the great solution! You may want to add this as an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131191/in-r-how-to-add-rows-with-0-counts-to-summarised-output since this question has been marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @RobJensen Will do if time permits. Thanks for hinting.