# data.table equivalent of tidyr::complete with group_by

Tags: r, data.table

I have a following data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 2, 2), 
  date1 = as.Date(c("2013-01-01", "2013-02-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-05-01")), 
  date2 = as.Date(c("2012-12-09", "2012-12-09", "2015-03-10", "2015-03-10"))
)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
     id      date1      date2
  <dbl>     <date>     <date>
1     1 2013-01-01 2012-12-09
2     1 2013-02-01 2012-12-09
3     2 2015-04-01 2015-03-10
4     2 2015-05-01 2015-03-10
```

And I want to complete this data frame such that for each `id`, there will be another `date1` value. This another `date1` value is computed as the next month. Also there is a `date2` value which is same for all `id`'s. With `tidyr::complete` this action can be done like this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  complete(date1 = seq.Date(from = min(date1), length.out = 3, by = "month"), date2 = date2[1])

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
     id      date1      date2
  <dbl>     <date>     <date>
1     1 2013-01-01 2012-12-09
2     1 2013-02-01 2012-12-09
3     1 2013-03-01 2012-12-09
4     2 2015-04-01 2015-03-10
5     2 2015-05-01 2015-03-10
6     2 2015-06-01 2015-03-10
```

Since I have about 150K groups in my original data, the `tidyr` solution is taking more than hour to complete. I am assuming that speed would be gained using `data.table`. Can the same thing be done in `data.table`?

Similar questions has been asked in [data.table equivalent of tidyr::complete()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483497/data-table-equivalent-of-tidyrcomplete) but without `group_by` clause.

Comment: Using `data.table` `setDT(df)[, .(date1 = seq(min(date1), length.out = 3, by = 'month'), date2 = date2[1]), id]`

Comment: See @Uwe's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330683/inserting-rows-into-data-frame-when-values-missing-in-category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on some initial benchmarking the `data.table` approach seems to be faster

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(date1 = seq(min(date1), length.out = 3, by = 'month'), date2 = date2[1]), id]
```

#### Benchmarks

```
 df <- data_frame(
  id = rep(1:3000, each = 2), 
  date1 = rep(as.Date(c("2013-01-01", "2013-02-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-05-01")),
  length.out = 6000), 
  date2 = rep(as.Date(c("2012-12-09", "2012-12-09", "2015-03-10", "2015-03-10")), 
   length.out = 6000))

system.time({
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  complete(date1 = seq.Date(from = min(date1), 
          length.out = 3, by = "month"), date2 = date2[1])
})
#user  system elapsed 
#64.05   21.27   86.05 

system.time({
setDT(df)[, .(date1 = seq(min(date1), length.out = 3, by = 'month'), date2 = date2[1]), id]
})
#user  system elapsed 
#  0.14    0.00    0.14
```

Comment: Is that data.table code equivalent? Seems like you'd take an object like your result and then left join to the main table to "complete"..?

Comment: @Frank It is a different way, but `system.time({
+  setDT(df)[df[,.(date1 = seq(min(date1), length.out = 3, by = 'month'), date2 = date2[1]), id], on = .(id, date1, date2)]
+ })#
   user  system elapsed 
   0.31    0.03    0.59` is still giving me less time

Answer (score 0):

If you need the speed, keeping the by as lean as possible:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

> dt[, .SD
     ][, .(date1=max(date1)), .(id, date2)
     ][, date1Inc := date1 + months(1)
     ][, rbind(dt, .SD[, .(id, date1=date1Inc, date2)])
     ][order(id, date1)
     ]

   id      date1      date2
1:  1 2013-01-01 2012-12-09
2:  1 2013-02-01 2012-12-09
3:  1 2013-03-01 2012-12-09
4:  2 2015-04-01 2015-03-10
5:  2 2015-05-01 2015-03-10
6:  2 2015-06-01 2015-03-10
>   
>
```