# data.table equivalent of tidyr::complete()

Tags: r, data.table, tidyr, tidyverse

`tidyr::complete()` adds rows to a `data.frame` for combinations of column values that are missing from the data. Example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(person = c(1,2,2),
                 observation_id = c(1,1,2),
                 value = c(1,1,1))
df %>%
  tidyr::complete(person,
                  observation_id,
                  fill = list(value=0))
```

yields

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  person observation_id value
   <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl>
1      1              1     1
2      1              2     0
3      2              1     1
4      2              2     1
```

where the `value` of the combination `person == 1` and `observation_id == 2` that is missing in `df` has been filled in with a value of 0.

What would be the equivalent of this in `data.table`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I reckon that the philosophy of data.table entails fewer specially-named functions for tasks than you'll find in the tidyverse, so some extra coding is required, like:

```
res = setDT(df)[
  CJ(person = person, observation_id = observation_id, unique=TRUE), 
  on=.(person, observation_id)
]
```

After this, you still have to manually handle the filling of values for missing levels. We can use `setnafill` to handle this efficiently & by-reference in recent versions of `data.table`:

```
setnafill(res, fill = 0, cols = 'value')
```

See [@Jealie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43483729/) regarding a feature that will sidestep this.

---

Certainly, it's crazy that the column names have to be entered three times here. But on the other hand, one can write a wrapper:

```
completeDT <- function(DT, cols, defs = NULL){
  mDT = do.call(CJ, c(DT[, ..cols], list(unique=TRUE)))
  res = DT[mDT, on=names(mDT)]
  if (length(defs)) 
    res[, names(defs) := Map(replace, .SD, lapply(.SD, is.na), defs), .SDcols=names(defs)]
  res[]
} 

completeDT(setDT(df), cols = c("person", "observation_id"), defs = c(value = 0))

   person observation_id value
1:      1              1     1
2:      1              2     0
3:      2              1     1
4:      2              2     1
```

As a quick way of avoiding typing the names three times for the first step, here's @thelatemail's idea:

```
vars <- c("person","observation_id")
df[do.call(CJ, c(mget(vars), unique=TRUE)), on=vars]

# or with magrittr...
c("person","observation_id") %>% df[do.call(CJ, c(mget(.), unique=TRUE)), on=.]
```

Update: now you don't need to enter names twice in CJ thanks to @MichaelChirico & @MattDowle for [the improvement](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/2977).

Answer (score 9):

There might be a better answer out there, but this works:

```
dt[CJ(person=unique(dt$person), 
      observation_id=unique(dt$observation_id)),
   on=c('person','observation_id')]
```

Which gives:

```
   person observation_id value
1:      1              1     1
2:      2              1     1
3:      1              2    NA
4:      2              2     1
```

Now, if you would like to be able to fill with any value (and not `NA`), I would suggest to wait for the [corresponding feature](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/857) to be finished or contribute to it :)

Answer (score 3):

It is worth noting that the `completeDT` function above doesn't carry many of the features that `tidyr::complete` does. In particular, empty factor levels are dropped - unlike `tidyr::complete` which keeps them. If you do want to keep empty factor the function can be edited as below. The `make_vals` function below could be made more sophisticated to handle other variable classes eg. full sequence for integers.

```r
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)


dat <- data.frame(
  person = c(1,2,2),
  observation_id = factor(c(1,1,2), 1:3),
  value = c(1,1,1))

dat %>%
  tidyr::complete(
    person, observation_id, fill = list(value=0))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   person observation_id value
#>    <dbl> <fct>          <dbl>
#> 1      1 1                  1
#> 2      1 2                  0
#> 3      1 3                  0
#> 4      2 1                  1
#> 5      2 2                  1
#> 6      2 3                  0

completeDT <- function(DT, cols, defs = NULL){
  
  make_vals <- function(col) {
    if(is.factor(col)) factor(levels(col))
    else unique(col)
  }
  
  mDT = do.call(CJ, c(lapply(DT[, ..cols], make_vals), list(unique=TRUE)))
  res = DT[mDT, on=names(mDT)]
  if (length(defs)) 
    res[, names(defs) := Map(replace, .SD, lapply(.SD, is.na), defs), .SDcols=names(defs)]
  res[]
} 

completeDT(DT = setDT(dat), cols = c("person", "observation_id"), defs = c(value = 0))
#>    person observation_id value
#> 1:      1              1     1
#> 2:      1              2     0
#> 3:      1              3     0
#> 4:      2              1     1
#> 5:      2              2     1
#> 6:      2              3     0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>