# Populate missing dates using groupby another column

Tags: r

I want to include the missing dates in the data frame DF  for each bodlane

DF:

```
Bodlane                      Day           Holiday
185_AB1                     2020-05-01      True
185_AB1                     2020-05-05      True
201_AB1                     2020-05-02      True
201_AB1                     2020-05-05      True
```

Output:

```
Bodlane                      Day           Holiday
185_AB1                     2020-05-01      True
185_AB1                     2020-05-02      NA
185_AB1                     2020-05-03      NA
185_AB1                     2020-05-04      NA
185_AB1                     2020-05-05      True
201_AB1                     2020-05-02      True
201_AB1                     2020-05-03      NA
201_AB1                     2020-05-04      NA
201_AB1                     2020-05-05      True
```

Can someone help me in getting the missing dates for each bodlane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `complete()` function in the tidyverse does what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table("Bodlane                      Day           Holiday
185_AB1                     2020-05-01      True
185_AB1                     2020-05-05      True
201_AB1                     2020-05-02      True
201_AB1                     2020-05-05      True")

df %>% 
  group_by(Bodlane) %>% 
  complete(Day = seq.Date(min(Day), max(Day), by = "d")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which gives

```
  Bodlane Day        Holiday
  <chr>   <date>     <lgl>  
1 185_AB1 2020-05-01 TRUE   
2 185_AB1 2020-05-02 NA     
3 185_AB1 2020-05-03 NA     
4 185_AB1 2020-05-04 NA     
5 185_AB1 2020-05-05 TRUE   
6 201_AB1 2020-05-02 TRUE   
7 201_AB1 2020-05-03 NA     
8 201_AB1 2020-05-04 NA     
9 201_AB1 2020-05-05 TRUE
```

Comment: It's taking a lot of time as I have records in millions. Can it be done in a faster way?

Comment: I'm not a `data.table` expert, but maybe that would speed things up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483497/data-table-equivalent-of-tidyrcomplete