# How to efficiently compute a convolution with missing data rows, without expanding the missing rows?

Tags: r, convolution

Imagine a tank of some volatile fluid which evaporates at a predictable rate. The tank receives some amount of the fluid every now and then and we want to model how much fluid is in the tank each time new fluid is added.

(Note this is not my actual problem, it is an analogy).

First, generate some sample data

```
library(tidyverse)

rm(list = ls())

set.seed(123)

original_data <-
  tibble(
    t = sample(50, 10, replace = FALSE),
    amount_incoming = runif(n = 10)
  )
```

Take a look at the data

```
original_data |>
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = t, y = amount_incoming) +
  geom_col(width = 0.7)
```

[image]

The data does not contain rows to represent the amount in between adding new fluid

```
# A tibble: 10 × 2
       t amount_incoming
   <int>           <dbl>
 1    31          0.900 
 2    15          0.246 
 3    14          0.0421
 4     3          0.328 
 5    42          0.955 
 6    43          0.890 
 7    37          0.693 
 8    48          0.641 
 9    25          0.994 
10    26          0.656
```

In order to compute this amount I must 'complete' the data set by adding the missing rows

```
completed_data <-
  original_data |>
  complete(t = full_seq(t, period = 1)) |>
  mutate(amount_incoming = replace_na(amount_incoming, 0))

# A tibble: 46 × 2
       t amount_incoming
   <dbl>           <dbl>
 1     3           0.328
 2     4           0    
 3     5           0    
 4     6           0    
 5     7           0    
 6     8           0    
 7     9           0    
 8    10           0    
 9    11           0    
10    12           0    
# ℹ 36 more rows
```

I use a slightly modified version of the `convolve` function to get the behaviour I want:

```
my_convolve = function(x, f){
  n_x = length(x)
  convolve(x, f, type = "o") |> head(n_x) |> zapsmall()
}

decay_rate_filter <- dexp(100:0, rate = 1)

convolved_data <-
  completed_data |>
  mutate(
    amount_held = my_convolve(amount_incoming, decay_rate_filter)
  )

convolved_data |>
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = t, y = amount_held) +
  geom_col(width = 0.7)
```

[image]

But I have no use for the extra rows so I filter them out

```
final_data <-
  convolved_data |>
  filter(amount_incoming != 0)
```

My actual problem involves a lot of data, and using this method is very slow. The slow part is the `complete` function from the `tidyr` package.
Is there an efficient way to get to my end state without using `complete`?

My last resort would be to write my own custom convolve function using `Rcpp` but wondering if there is some pre-existing solution, since I imagine I am not the first to have this requirement.

Comment: Some potential solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483497/data-table-equivalent-of-tidyrcomplete

Comment: Since the input signal containing the incoming fluid is seemingly sparse, what about computing the convolution directly in the time domain using sparse convolution? Here is an article that describes it: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-does-sparse-convolution-work-3257a0a8fd1 and here are the two main papers referenced by the above article with the theoretical background (https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10275 ("3D Semantic Segmentation with Submanifold Sparse Convolutional Networks", 2017)) and implementation ("SECOND: Sparsely Embeded Convolutional Detection", Yan, Mao, Li, 2018)

Comment: @mastropi, this is exactly what I am looking for, I just didn't have the words to describe it. Is is also what I mean by my last resort being to write my own custom convolve function using Rcpp. So, now that I have the words to describe it, I am looking for an out of the box function for sparse convolution.

Comment: Good to know @ChechyLevas. In case you are interested, I would be happy in collaborating with you in the development of such Rcpp implementation. What motivates me is: (i) I am interested in signal processing techniques, in particular in making them more efficient, and (ii) I would like to increase my exposure with Rcpp development, as I would like to speed up a Bayesian Wavelet Thresholding method that would greatly benefit from such type of implementation. So, in case you are interested, I propose that you reach out to me via LinkedIn: www.linkedin.com/in/danielmastropietro

Answer (score 0):

A data.table version which (ab)uses the key to create a equivalent of the tidyr complete function as called.  It appears to scale well in my tests with a 500 million range of `t` and 10 million incoming amounts.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(123)

original_data <- data.table(
  t = sample(50, 10, replace = FALSE),
  amount_incoming = runif(n = 10)
)

# This is equivalent to complete(original_data, t = full_seq(t, period = 1))
setkey(original_data, t)
dt_complete <- original_data[.(seq(min(t), max(t), 1))]
```

This assumes that your `original_data` `t` values are in the expanded sequence of complete values `seq(min(t), max(t), 1)`, and it may give unexpected downstream results if the `t` values in `original_data` are not unique.