# Getting a count of specific values in a data frame that appear in another

Tags: r, dplyr, match, countif

This question may sound similar to others, but I hope it is different enough.
I want to take a specific list of values and count how often they appear in another list of values where non-occurring values are retuned as '0'.

I have a Data Frame (df1) with the following values:

```
Items <- c('Carrots','Plums','Pineapple','Turkey')   
df1<-data.frame(Items)

>df1
Items
1   Carrots
2     Plums
3 Pineapple
4    Turkey
```

And a second Data Frame (df2) that contains a column called 'Thing':

```
> head(df2,n=10)
  ID       Date     Thing
1  58150 2012-09-12  Potatoes
2  12357 2012-09-28   Turnips
3  50788 2012-10-04   Oranges
4  66038 2012-10-11  Potatoes
5  18119 2012-10-11   Oranges
6  48349 2012-10-14   Carrots
7  23328 2012-10-16   Peppers
8  66038 2012-10-26 Pineapple
9  32717 2012-10-28   Turnips
10 11345 2012-11-08   Oranges
```

I know the word 'Turkey' only appears in df1 NOT in df2. I want to return a frequency table or count of the items in df1 that appears in df2 and return '0' for the count of Turkey.

How can I summarize values of on Data Frame column using the values from another? The closest I got was:

```
df2%>% count (Thing) %>% filter(Thing %in% df1$Items,)
```

But this return a list of items filtered between df1 and df2 so 'Turkey' gets excluded. So close!

```
> df2%>% count (Thing) %>% filter(Thing %in% df1$Items,)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      Thing     n
     <fctr> <int>
1   Carrots    30
2 Pineapple    30
3     Plums    38
```

I want my output to look like this:

```
1   Carrots    30
2 Pineapple    30
3     Plums    38
4    Turkey     0
```

I am newish to R and completely new to dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

I use this sort of thing all the time. I'm sure there's a more savvy way to code it, but it's what I got:

```
item <- vector()
count <- vector()
items <- list(unique(df1$Items))

for (i in 1:length(items)){
    item[i] <- items[i]
    count[i] <- sum(df2$Thing == item)
}

df3 <- data.frame(cbind(item, count))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I received a length warning:                                      `longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Comment: Ahh I think I know why.

So the code above looks at EVERY item, not just unique items. I've updated my comment try that.

Comment: I am still getting the same error, but I see what your script is trying to achieve. I created df1 comes from a vector. Is there any way I could simplify the for loop using that original vector?

Comment: I got it! There needed to be a `[i]` after item when populating count!

Comment: Good job, Jacob!

Answer (score 0):

Stephen's solution worked with a slight modification, adding the [i] to the item at the end of count[i] line. See below:

```
item <- vector() 
count <- vector()

for (i in 1:length(unique(Items))){ 
    item[i] <- Items[i] 
    count[i]<- sum(df2$Thing == item[i])
} 

df3 <- data.frame(cbind(item, count))

> df3
       item count
1   Carrots    30
2     Plums    38
3 Pineapple    30
4    Turkey     0
```

Answer (score 0):

*dplyr* drops 0 count rows, and you have the added complication that the possible categories of `Thing` are different between your two datasets.

If you add the factor levels from `df1` to `df2`, you can use `complete` from *tidyr*, which is a common way to [add 0 count rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956178/proper-idiom-for-adding-zero-count-rows-in-tidyr-dplyr).

I'm adding the factor levels from `df1` to `df2` using a convenience function from package *forcats* called `fct_expand`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(forcats)

df2 %>% 
    mutate(Thing = fct_expand(Thing, as.character(df1$Item) ) ) %>%
    count(Thing) %>% 
    complete(Thing, fill = list(n = 0) ) %>%
    filter(Thing %in% df1$Items,)
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to aggregate `df2` first, to right join with `df1` (to pick all rows of `df1`), and to replace `NA` by zero.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
  count(Thing) %>% 
  right_join(unique(df1), by = c("Thing" = "Items")) %>% 
  mutate(n = coalesce(n, 0L))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 2
>       Thing     n
>       <chr> <int>
> 1   Carrots     1
> 2     Plums     0
> 3 Pineapple     1
> 4    Turkey     0
> Warning message:
> Column `Thing`/`Items` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
> ```

The same approach in  `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, .N, by = Thing][unique(setDT(df1)), on = .(Thing = Items)][is.na(N), N := 0L][]
```

> ```
>        Thing N
> 1:   Carrots 1
> 2:     Plums 0
> 3: Pineapple 1
> 4:    Turkey 0
> ```

Note that in both implementations `unique(df1)` is used to avoid unintended duplicate rows after the join.

**Edit 2019-06-22**: 
With [development version 1.12.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) `data.table` has gained a `coalesce()` function. So, above statement can be written

```
setDT(df2)[, .N, by = Thing][unique(setDT(df1)), on = .(Thing = Items)][, N := coalesce(N, 0L)][]
```

---

If `df2` is large and `df1` contains only a few `Items` it might be more efficient to join first and then to aggregate:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
  right_join(unique(df1), by = c("Thing" = "Items")) %>% 
  group_by(Thing) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(!is.na(ID)))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 2
>       Thing     n
>       <chr> <int>
> 1   Carrots     1
> 2 Pineapple     1
> 3     Plums     0
> 4    Turkey     0
> Warning message:
> Column `Thing`/`Items` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
> ```

The same in `data.table syntax`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[unique(setDT(df1)), on = .(Thing = Items)][, .(N = sum(!is.na(ID))), by = Thing][]
```

> ```
>        Thing N
> 1:   Carrots 1
> 2:     Plums 0
> 3: Pineapple 1
> 4:    Turkey 0
> ```

**Edit 2019-06-22:** Above can be written more concisely by *aggregating in a join*:

```
setDT(df2)[setDT(df1), on = .(Thing = Items), .N, by = .EACHI]
```