# dplyr - check if month is there, if not, add it in with an NA

Tags: r, dplyr

close but not a duplicate: [Proper idiom for adding zero count rows in tidyr/dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956178/proper-idiom-for-adding-zero-count-rows-in-tidyr-dplyr) - I am trying to fill based on existing values in df, but also fill based on data that does not have an `id`. Similar, but fundamentally different.

For each `id`, I am trying to make sure each has 3 billing months.

Ideally, for each `id` I need all three `required months` to be present in `df_complete`. If it is not in the data, I am looking to add a row with "Not found" for the values.

Additionally, I want to check against `all_ids` and add ids that are in `all_ids` but do not have rows in `df`

```
months <- as.data.frame(as.Date(c("2016/7/1","2016/9/1","2016/7/1", "2016/8/1","2016/9/1", "2016/8/1","2016/9/1"))) 
id <- as.data.frame(c("a","a","b","b","b","c","c"))
value <- as.data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
df <- cbind(id,months,value)
colnames(df) <- c("id","billing months","value")
required_months <- as.data.frame(as.Date(c("2016/7/1", "2016/8/1","2016/9/1")))
colnames(required_months)<- "required months"
all_ids <- as.data.frame(c("a","b", "c", "d"))
```

df ends up looking like:

```
id  billing months  value
a   7/1/2016    1
a   9/1/2016    2
b   7/1/2016    3
b   8/1/2016    4
b   9/1/2016    5
c   8/1/2016    6
c   9/1/2016    7
```

What I'm looking for (`df_complete`):

```
id  billing months  value
a   7/1/2016    1
a   8/1/2016    Not Found
a   9/1/2016    2
b   7/1/2016    3
b   8/1/2016    4
b   9/1/2016    5
c   7/1/2016    Not Found
c   8/1/2016    6
c   9/1/2016    7
d   7/1/2016    Not Found
d   8/1/2016    Not Found
d   9/1/2016    Not Found
```

Looking for a `dplyr` solution, but other packages work too.

Comment: Check function `complete` from `tidyr`.

Comment: I also think it's better if you use `required_months <- as.Date(c("2016/7/1", "2016/8/1","2016/9/1"))` and
`all_ids <- c("a","b", "c", "d")` as vectors instead of data frames, so they can be used directly within `complete` function.

Comment: For reference, a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25956178/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a job for `tidyr::complete`.  As you are missing both id variables and months in your original dataset, you'll need to define the values you need filled in via `complete`.  You define what you want to the missing values entered as with `fill` (although your `Not found` value will change your column from one that was potentially a column of numbers to a column of characters).

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages( library(dplyr) )
library(tidyr)

df %>%
    complete(id = c("a","b", "c", "d"), 
             `billing months` = required_months$`required months`,
             fill = list(value = "Not found") )

#> Warning: Column `id` joining character vector and factor, coercing into
#> character vector

#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>    id    `billing months` value    
#>    <chr> <date>           <chr>    
#>  1 a     2016-07-01       1        
#>  2 a     2016-08-01       Not found
#>  3 a     2016-09-01       2        
#>  4 b     2016-07-01       3        
#>  5 b     2016-08-01       4        
#>  6 b     2016-09-01       5        
#>  7 c     2016-07-01       Not found
#>  8 c     2016-08-01       6        
#>  9 c     2016-09-01       7        
#> 10 d     2016-07-01       Not found
#> 11 d     2016-08-01       Not found
#> 12 d     2016-09-01       Not found
```

Created on 2018-03-29 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: OP has an object all_ids you can use instead of typing the vector out again `tidyr::complete(df, id = all_ids[[1]], \`billing months\` = required_months[[1]], fill = list(value = "nope"))`

Comment: @Frank Thanks.  I realize that, but because I could copy and paste the vector the OP had written out I lazily chose that route rather than typing out an additional object name. :)