# Count number of each factor grouping by another factor

Tags: r, count, dplyr, factors

I know the answer to this question will be simple but I have searched the forums extensively and I have been unable to find a solution.

I have a column called `Data_source` which is a factor that I want to group my variables by.

I have a series of `symptom*` variables where I want the counts according to `Data_source`.

For some reason, I am unable to figure out how to do this. The normal `group_by` functions do not seem to work appropriately.

Here is the dataframe in question

```
 df <- wrapr::build_frame(
   "Data_source"  , "Sex"   , "symptoms_decLOC", "symptoms_nausea_vomitting" |
     "1"          , "Female", NA_character_    , NA_character_               |
     "1"          , "Female", NA_character_    , NA_character_               |
     "1"          , "Female", "No"             , NA_character_               |
     "1"          , "Female", "Yes"            , "No"                        |
     "1"          , "Female", "Yes"            , "No"                        |
     "1"          , "Female", "Yes"            , "No"                        |
     "1"          , "Male"  , "Yes"            , "No"                        |
     "1"          , "Female", "Yes"            , "No"                        |
     "2"          , "Female", NA_character_    , NA_character_               |
     "2"          , "Male"  , NA_character_    , NA_character_               |
     "2"          , "Male"  , NA_character_    , NA_character_               |
     "2"          , "Female", "Yes"            , "No"                        |
     "2"          , "Female", "Yes"            , "No"                        |
     "2"          , "Male"  , NA_character_    , NA_character_               |
     "2"          , "Male"  , NA_character_    , NA_character_               |
     "2"          , "Male"  , NA_character_    , NA_character_               |
     "2"          , "Female", NA_character_    , NA_character_               |
     "2"          , "Female", NA_character_    , NA_character_               |
     "2"          , "Male"  , NA_character_    , NA_character_               |
     "2"          , "Female", NA_character_    , NA_character_               )
```

Notice that Sex and the symptoms variables are all factors which include NA's. I have attempted the following

```
df %>% na.omit() %>% group_by(Data_source) %>% count("symptoms_decLOC")
```

Which does not work and is less than optimal because I would have to repeat it for every column. The ideal would be to use something similar to `lapply(df, count)` but this does not give me description for each group.

*EDIT*

In response to question below, I have added the expected output. I have edited this in excel, color coding the `group_by` for clarity.

[image]

Notice how I am getting a break down for each possible answer. When I run this using `dplyr` here is the output.

```
> df %>% na.omit() %>% group_by(Data_source) %>% count("symptoms_decLOC")
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   Data_source [2]
  Data_source `"symptoms_decLOC"`     n
  <chr>       <chr>               <int>
1 1           symptoms_decLOC         5
2 2           symptoms_decLOC         2
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I should have put this in the original question. I have made an EDIT to further clarify what I am looking for

Answer (score 2):

This gets most of the way: haven't figured out how to include zero-count groups yet ... supposedly adding [.drop=FALSE takes care of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956178/proper-idiom-for-adding-zero-count-rows-in-tidyr-dplyr), but it's not working for me (using `dplyr` v. 0.8.0.9001).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
(df
    %>% tidyr::gather(var,val,-Data_source)
    %>% count(Data_source,var,val, .drop=FALSE)
    %>% na.omit()
)
```

Results:

```
  Data_source var                       val        n
  <chr>       <chr>                     <chr>  <int>
1 1           Sex                       Female     7
2 1           Sex                       Male       1
3 1           symptoms_decLOC           No         1
4 1           symptoms_decLOC           Yes        5
5 1           symptoms_nausea_vomitting No         5
6 2           Sex                       Female     6
7 2           Sex                       Male       6
8 2           symptoms_decLOC           Yes        2
9 2           symptoms_nausea_vomitting No         2
```

Comment: Using this syntax I don't get the same output as you. I get  `Error in count(., Data_source, var, val, .drop = FALSE) : 
  unused arguments (val, .drop = FALSE)`

Comment: what are the results of `find("count")` (and packageVersion("dplyr")`) ?

Comment: [Here is a link to the output](https://i.imgur.com/1BR09Gk.png)

`> find("count")
[1] "package:plyr"  "package:dplyr"
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘0.8.0.1’`

Comment: Alright so since both packages are being loaded if I change your code to `dplyr::count` I get the expected output! Thanks

Comment: You probably got a warning that some functions were being masked when you loaded `plyr` after `dplyr` ...

Answer (score 1):

Using @Ben Bolker's answer to get counts for each group, using `spread` and `gather` to include zero count groups.

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Count number of occurences by Data_source 
df2 <- 
  df %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -Data_source) %>% 
  count(Data_source, variable, value, name = "counter") %>%
  na.omit() 

# For variable = "Sex", leave as is
# For everything else, in this case symptom* convert into factor to include zero count group
# Then spread with dataframe will NAs filled with 0, re-convert back to long to bind rows
bind_rows(df2 %>%
            filter(variable == "Sex"), 

          df2 %>%
            filter(variable != "Sex") %>%
            mutate(value = factor(value, levels = c("Yes", "No"))) %>%
            spread(key = value, value = counter, fill = 0) %>%
            gather(value, counter, -Data_source, -variable))  %>%

  arrange(Data_source, variable)
```

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)

# Melt data by Data source
dt_melt <- melt(dt, id.vars = "Data_source", value.factor = FALSE, variable.factor = FALSE)

# Add counter, if NA then 0 else 1
dt_melt[, counter := 0]
dt_melt[!is.na(value), counter := 1]

# Sum number of occurrences
dt_count <- dt_melt[,list(counter = sum(counter)), by = c("Data_source", "variable", "value")]

# Split into two dt
dt2a <- dt_count[variable == "Sex", ]
dt2b <- dt_count[variable != "Sex" ,]

# only on symptoms variables
# Convert into factor variable
dt2b$value <- factor(dt2b$value, levels = c("Yes", "No"))
dt2b_dcast <- dcast(data = dt2b, formula = Data_source + variable ~ value, value.var = "counter", fill = 0, drop = FALSE)
dt2b_melt <- melt(dt2b_dcast, id.vars = c("Data_source", "variable"), variable.name = "value", value.name = "counter") 

# combine
combined_d <- rbind(dt2a, dt2b_melt)
combined_d[order(Data_source, variable), ]
```

Comment: Ya I am still unable to get the dplyr method working. Data.table does work but it adds a tremendous amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you're asking, but I'll asume you want to count the number of non-NA values in each of your `symptom_*` columns.

This is a `data.table` solution:

```
# load library

library(data.table)

# Suppose the table is called "dt". Convert it to a data.table:

setDT(dt)

# convert the wide table to a long one, filter the values that
# aren't NA and count both, by Data_source and by variable
# (variable is the created column with the symptom_* names)

melt(dt, id.vars = 1:2)[!is.na(value), 
                        .N, 
                         by = .(Data_source, variable)]
```

What each part of the code is doing:

`melt(dt, id.vars = 1:2)` converts `dt` from wide to long, and keeps columns 1 and 2 (Data_source and `sex`) as fixed.

`!is.na(value)` filters the values (that were previously under each `symptom_*` header) that are not `NA`.

`.N` counts the rows.

`by = .(Data_source, variable)` is the grouping we are using to count. `variable` is the name of the column where the `symptom_*` landed during the reshaping.

Comment: When I run this I get the following 
 
        Data_source                  variable N
     1:           1           symptoms_decLOC 6
     2:           2           symptoms_decLOC 2
     3:           1 symptoms_nausea_vomitting 5
     4:           2 symptoms_nausea_vomitting 2

This is not giving me stats for each individual response.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, the hard thing is to keep combinations that don't exist in the data... Here is a solution in two steps :

**1. Prepare a database without count**

You can do whatever you want, but I've chosen to compute two chunks since the modalities are different for the variable `Sex`. No need to bind those chunks here.

```r
chunk1 <- expand.grid(
  Data_source = c("1", "2"),
  name = c("symptoms_decLOC", "symptoms_nausea_vomitting"),
  value = c("Yes", "No"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

chunk2 <- expand.grid(
  Data_source = c("1", "2"),
  name = "Sex",
  value = c("Female", "Male"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

**2. Finish the job asked**

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c("Sex", "symptoms_decLOC", "symptoms_nausea_vomitting"))%>%
  group_by(Data_source, name, value) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  right_join(bind_rows(chunk1, chunk2), by = c("Data_source", "name", "value")) %>%
  arrange(Data_source, name) %>%
  mutate(count = zoo::na.fill(count, 0))
```

**Et voilà**

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   Data_source, name [6]
   Data_source name                      value  count
   <chr>       <chr>                     <chr>  <int>
 1 1           Sex                       Female     7
 2 1           Sex                       Male       1
 3 1           symptoms_decLOC           Yes        5
 4 1           symptoms_decLOC           No         1
 5 1           symptoms_nausea_vomitting Yes        0
 6 1           symptoms_nausea_vomitting No         5
 7 2           Sex                       Female     6
 8 2           Sex                       Male       6
 9 2           symptoms_decLOC           Yes        2
10 2           symptoms_decLOC           No         0
11 2           symptoms_nausea_vomitting Yes        0
12 2           symptoms_nausea_vomitting No         2
```

It is not so short, but it uses simple functions. The process is similar as that one can do in Excel i.e., prepare the structure and then complete the counts.

I hope it could help ;-)