# Add in "empty" rows when joining tables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am working on an application that monitors worker productivity in R. For each worker I have the jobs they completed and I want to see how many jobs they completed each week of the year ( so weeks 1 - 52). The issue is that some workers don't have any work logged for certain weeks (e.g. Worker 1 might have worked weeks 1 - 48, but not 49 - 52).

The source data is tables for each job top where the observation is the worker, formatted like so:

```
UniqueID  Date     mapper
10000001 3/3/2015  person1
```

Starting with this I then break the date up into year, month, day fields and then use `lubridate` to get the weeks. This is applied to each source data file (of which there are 10).

I then group each table by the user and week and count the number of jobs each worker completed, see code here:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(rlang)
library(pryr)
library(lubridate)
library(extrafont)
loadfonts(device = "win")


current_week <- week(Sys.Date())
feature_sheets <- excel_sheets("./typesMerged.xlsx")
list_sheets <- lapply(feature_sheets, function(x) read_excel(path = "./typesMerged.xlsx",col_types = c("numeric", "date", "text"), sheet = x))

users = list('person1', 'person2', 'person3', 'person4', 'person5', 'person6')


createTibble <- function(i, yr, wk){
  is_missing <- missing(wk)
  list_sheets[[i]]%>%
    filter(LASTUSER %in% users ) %>% 
    mutate(year = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%Y")),
           month = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%m")),
           week = week(DATEMODIFI),
           day = as.numeric(format(DATEMODIFI, format = "%d")))%>% 
    select(-DATEMODIFI) %>%
    filter(year == yr) %>%
    filter(if(is_missing) TRUE else week == wk) 
}




tableNames <- c('dpd', 'fuse', 'ohprimary', 'ohsecondary', 'poles', 'pv', 'switch','transformers', 'ugprimary', 'ugsecondary' )
features <- vector('list', length(tableNames))


for (feature in seq_along(features)){

  features[[feature]] <- createTibble(i = feature, yr = 2019)


}

# use for iteratively creating tibbles/df if needed
# for (feature in seq_along(features)){
#   assign(features[feature], value = createTibble(feature))
# }


countFeatures <- function(x){
  x %>%
    group_by(LASTUSER, week) %>%
    summarize(n = n())
}


featureCountTibbles <-map(.x = features,.f = countFeatures)

featureCountsByUser <- featureCountTibbles %>% reduce(full_join, by = c("LASTUSER", "week")) %>% 
  rename(mapper = LASTUSER) %>% 
  rename(dpd = n.x) %>%
  rename(fuse = n.y) %>% 
  rename(ohprimary = n.x.x) %>% 
  rename(ohsecondary = n.y.y) %>% 
  rename(poles = n.x.x.x) %>% 
  rename(pv = n.y.y.y) %>% 
  rename(switch = n.x.x.x.x) %>% 
  rename(transformers = n.y.y.y.y) %>% 
  rename(ugprimary = n.x.x.x.x.x) %>% 
  rename(ugsecondary = n.y.y.y.y.y) %>% 
  replace_na(replace = list(dpd = 0, fuse = 0, ohprimary = 0, ohsecondary = 0, poles = 0, pv = 0, switch = 0, transformers = 0, ugprimary = 0, ugsecondary = 0))
```

this results in a table that looks like this, the problem here is that person1 did no work in week 5 so he doesn't have a row for it:

```
mapper  week  dpd  fuse  etc.
person1  1    10    50   ...
person1  2     0    50   ...
person1  3    10     0   ...
person1  4    10    50   ...
person1  6    10    50   ...
person2  1    10    50   ...
person2  2    50    50   ...
person2  3    10     0   ...
person2  4    10    50   ...
person2  5    10    50   ***
person2  6    10    50   ...
```

This is how I want it to look where weeks of no work are seen:

```
mapper  week  dpd  fuse  etc.
person1  1    10    50   ...
person1  2     0    50   ...
person1  3    10     0   ...
person1  4    10    50   ...
person1  5     0     0   ***
person1  6    10    50   ...
person2  1    10    50   ...
person2  2    50    50   ...
person2  3    10     0   ...
person2  4    10    50   ...
person2  5    10    50   ...
person2  6    10    50   ...
```

How can I make it so these empty rows will be added? It sounds simple, but I can't really think of a way to do it in R (still kind of new to it). If this was SQL I would add a new field week at the beginning, populate it with 1 - 52 (which would add in all the rows I need) and then update the table with the actual data I have for the weeks.

Solution Implemented:

```r
featureCountsByUser <- featureCountTibbles %>% reduce(full_join, by = c("LASTUSER", "week")) %>%
  rename(mapper = LASTUSER) %>%
  rename(dpd = n.x) %>%
  rename(fuse = n.y) %>% 
  rename(ohprimary = n.x.x) %>% 
  rename(ohsecondary = n.y.y) %>% 
  rename(poles = n.x.x.x) %>% 
  rename(pv = n.y.y.y) %>% 
  rename(switch = n.x.x.x.x) %>% 
  rename(transformers = n.y.y.y.y) %>% 
  rename(ugprimary = n.x.x.x.x.x) %>% 
  rename(ugsecondary = n.y.y.y.y.y) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  complete(mapper,week) %>% 
  group_by(mapper,week) %>% 
  replace_na(replace = list(dpd = 0, fuse = 0, ohprimary = 0, ohsecondary = 0, poles = 0, pv = 0, switch = 0, transformers = 0, ugprimary = 0, ugsecondary = 0))
```

`complete()` was the answer; but contrary to the docs it did not respect my grouping and due to the nature of how I am counting jobs done I could not `complete()` on the raw data so this is my work around. Thanks all!

Comment: Create a tibble with all the columns I need and rows blank, then feed in the results of this script into it?

Comment: It sound like you may want `tidyr::complete()`.  You can see one example of its use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37728065/2461552).  If grouping at some point, the new `.drop = FALSE` feature may also help, shown in another answer at the same link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the results data you posted that isn't what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- c("Worker  Week  dpd  fuse ", 
  "person1  1    10    5   ",
  "person1  2     0    5   ",
  "person1  3    10        ",
  "person1  4    10    5   ",
  "person1  6    10    5   ",
  "person2  1    10    5   ",
  "person2  2    50    5   ",
  "person2  3    10        ",
  "person2  4    10    5   ",
  "person2  5    10    5   ",
  "person2  6    10    5   ") %>%
  read_table()


x %>% complete(Worker, Week)
```

Should give:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   Worker   Week   dpd  fuse
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 person1     1    10     5
 2 person1     2     0     5
 3 person1     3    10    NA
 4 person1     4    10     5
 5 person1     5    NA    NA
 6 person1     6    10     5
 7 person2     1    10     5
 8 person2     2    50     5
 9 person2     3    10    NA
10 person2     4    10     5
11 person2     5    10     5
12 person2     6    10     5
```

`complete()` has a options for filling in missing data, link to reference above by @aosmith.  Filling NA with 0 shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get it to work exactly how you outlined, but it lead me to the solution (see update in original post). For whatever reason complete was not respecting my group_by() and I could not apply ```complete()``` on the raw data as the counts for completed jobs depends on the original data being as is (i.e. if I add weeks that aren't there it'll make it look like they completed jobs when they did not).