# How to make dplyr not throw error when filter argument is all FALSE?

Tags: r, dplyr

Example setup:

```
> first <- function(value) {
  if(length(value)==0) {
    return(data.frame(out=NA,othercolumns=c(0,1)))
  } else {
    return(data.frame(out=mean(value),othercolumns=c(1,1)))
  }
}
> set.seed(1)
> df <- data.frame(column1=runif(10),column2=runif(10),
                 category=sample(c("a","b"),10,replace=TRUE))
```

Chain of dplyr functions returns error:

```
> df %>% group_by(category) %>% filter(column2 > 1) %>% do(first(.$column1))
Error: incompatible number of rows (2, expecting 0
```

Is there a way to force dplyr to send the empty data frame to `do()` rather than throw an error?

**Update**

Following @Henrik's links, it appears the data frame needs to be converted to a `tbl_df()` object. The conversion though has to happen after the group_by() call:

```
> df %>% group_by(category) %>% tbl_df() %>%
  filter(column2 > 1) %>% do(first(.$column1))

+   out othercolumns
1  NA            0
2  NA            1
```

The syntax is strange and non-intuitive but works...

Though I would have expected output like

```
   category  out othercolumns
1  "a"       NA            0
2  "a"       NA            1
3  "b"       NA            0
4  "b"       NA            1
```

**Update 2**

Combining with plyr::ddply seems to work well:

```
> ddply(df,.(category),function(.) filter(.,column2 > 1) %>%
        do(first(.$column1)))

+   category out othercolumns
1        a  NA            0
2        a  NA            1
3        b  NA            0
4        b  NA            1
```

Comment: I haven't checked very carefully, but could your question possibly be related to [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523131/dplyr-summarise-equivalent-of-drop-false-to-keep-groups-with-zero-length-in)? See also [**here**](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/341).

Comment: Just looked at it briefly, but I'm pretty sure the empty data frame is being passed to `do`, but the problem arises when stitching everything back together. If I had to guess, dplyr is using the properties of the grouped df (e.g. that it is empty) to infer that it should be getting an empty data frame in return. Might be worth a github issue.

Comment: @Henrik, thanks- your second link eventually led me to the right answer. If you could provide an answer below regarding the `drop` option of the `tbl_df`/`grouped_df`, I can mark your answer to be correct.

Comment: It might also be related to this: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/625

Comment: @crippledlambda You seem to have read the links I posted more thoroughly than I have, so feel free to write up an answer. Cheers.