# Complete column with group_by and complete

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I've got a little problem using dplyr `group_by` function.
After doing this :

```
datasetALL %>% group_by(YEAR,Region) %>% summarise(count_number = n())
```

here is the result :

```
YEAR Region count_number
<int>  <int>        <int>
1   1946      1            2
2   1946      2            3
3   1946      3            1
4   1946      5            1
5   1947      3            1
6   1947      4            1
```

I would like something like :

```
YEAR Region count_number
<int>  <int>        <int>
1   1946      1            2
2   1946      2            3
3   1946      3            1
4   1946      5            1
5   1946      4            0 #order is not important
6   1947      1            0
7   1947      2            0
8   1947      3            1
9   1947      4            1
10  1947      5            0
```

I tried to use `complete()` from tidyr package, but it's not succeeding...

Comment: Can you add the code you tried using `complete`?

Comment: Please show us how you're using `complete`. Probably, you need to `ungroup` before you run `complete`. Also, it depends on what variables you are `nesting` within `complete`.

Comment: This previous question seems to cover it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523131/dplyr-summarise-equivalent-of-drop-false-to-keep-groups-with-zero-length-in

Comment: For example, run the following code with and without `ungroup`: `mtcars %>% group_by(carb, cyl) %>% tally %>% arrange(cyl, carb) %>% ungroup %>% complete(carb, nesting(cyl), fill=list(n=0))`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using `complete` from the tidyr package should work. You can find documentation about it [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.6.0/topics/complete).

What probably happened is that you did not remove the grouping. Then complete tries to add each of the combinations of `YEAR` and `Region` within each group. But all these combinations are already in the grouping. Thus first remove the grouping and then do the complete.

```
datasetALL %>% 
    group_by(YEAR,Region) %>% 
    summarise(count_number = n()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    complete(Year, Region, fill = list(count_number = 1))
```

Comment: `complete` documentation is awful and does not provide a simple example before launching into `complete/nesting`

Comment: You might say it's in`complete`

Answer (score 2):

It has been already mentioned, but you can solve this problem in its entirety by using `tidyr` and the parameter `nesting` in it:

```
complete(df, YEAR, nesting(Region), fill = list(count_number = 0))

    YEAR Region count_number
   <int>  <int>        <dbl>
 1  1946      1            2
 2  1946      2            3
 3  1946      3            1
 4  1946      4            0
 5  1946      5            1
 6  1947      1            0
 7  1947      2            0
 8  1947      3            1
 9  1947      4            1
10  1947      5            0
```