# How do I "fill down"/expand observations with respect to a time variable?

Tags: r

Suppose I have this dataset:

```
  Year  ID  Value
1 1999  1   1.3
2 2000  1   1.4
3 2001  1   1.5
4 2002  1   1.3
5 2003  1   5.0
6 2000  2   3.4
7 2003  2   1.2
```

I want `Year` variable to range from 1999 to 2003 for every ID/observation. Of course in extending the dataset, I am also creating NAs values for the variable `Value`. In other words, this is what I want:

```
   Year  ID  Value
1  1999   1   1.3
2  2000   1   1.4
3  2001   1   1.5
4  2002   1   1.3
5  2003   1   5.0
6  1999   2   NA
7  2000   2   3.4
8  2001   2   NA
9  2002   2   NA
10 2003   2   1.2
```

How do I do this on R?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501670/complete-column-with-group-by-and-complete

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it now.