# How can I complete a dataset and yet conserve variables

Tags: r, database, dataframe, tidyr

So I was revising what this guy asked: [How do I "fill down"/expand observations with respect to a time variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59060292/how-do-i-fill-down-expand-observations-with-respect-to-a-time-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I need the same thing for my dataset:

So they send him to check this:[Complete column with group_by and complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501670/complete-column-with-group-by-and-complete)  (i tried to replicate the answers codes, but they didn't worked)

So my dataset looks like this (I present a simplification, in the real dataset there are more variables, and the real dimensions are 631230 obs. of 21 variables)

`df`

```
Year   ID          Name  Brunch Sales  Wages   Labor productivity
2014   1750941579   JEN    A     3       2           1.5
2015   1750941579   JEN    A     4       2           2
2016   1750941579   JEN    A     6       4           1.5
2017   1750941579   JEN    A     8       4           2
2018   1750941579   JEN    A     8       4           2
2014   1303477204   MIC    B     6       2           3
2015   1303477204   MIC    B     8       4           2
```

so i used this code `DF<-complete(df, ID, Year=full_seq(Year, period=1),fill=list(Labor productivity=0))`

and got something like this

```
Year   ID           Name       Brunch     Sales  Wages   Labor productivity
2014   1750941579   JEN           A        3       2           1.5
2015   1750941579   JEN           A        4       2           2
2016   1750941579   JEN           A        6       4           1.5
2017   1750941579   JEN           A        8       4           2
2018   1750941579   JEN           A        8       4           2
2014   1303477204   MIC           B        6       2           3
2015   1303477204   MIC           B        8       4           2
2016   1303477204   #¿NOMBRE?     B        0       0           NaN
2017   1303477204    NA           NA       NA      NA          NA 
2018   1303477204    NA           NA       NA      NA          NA
```

It completed the panel, as I wanted, but is there a way to keep the Name, Brunch, (and other columns not listed here)?

It's fine if the quantitative variables (sales, wages) are NA or 0 i don't mind. But I need to keep the qualitative variables(Name and Brunch, that are associated with the ID).

I tried with this code from the second link (adaptation to my dataset)

```
DF<-df %>% 
  group_by(Year, ID) %>% 
  summarise(`Labor Productivity`=n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  complete(Year, ID, fill = list(`Labor Productivity`=1))
```

but i only get  `summarise() regrouping output by 'Year' (override with .groups argument)`

and the output dataset looks like this:

```
Year   ID          Name  Labor productivity
2014   1750941579   JEN        1
2014   1303477204   MIC        1
2015   1750941579   JEN        1
2015   1303477204   MIC        1
2016   1750941579   JEN        1
2016   1303477204   MIC        1
```

And so on... (dimensions: 631230 obs. of 3 variables)

So, second question: What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `fill` the variables that you want.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  complete(ID, Year=full_seq(Year, period=1),fill=list(Labor_productivity=0)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  fill(Name, Brunch)
```

Comment: Can you share some more details? What do you mean by `'didn't work'` ? What did you expect and what does my answer return?

Comment: Your answer gives me the same result as the second data frame I exposed `DF`.

Comment: I know why it didn't worked!  I had to delete this part `fill=list(labor_productivity=0)` and before the last `fill` i put this one: `df$Name[df$Name=="#¿NOMBRE?"]<-NA` then, the last fill, but i got the last `fill` like this: `fill(Name, Brunch,.direction="downup")` Thank you!!