# Including missing values in summarise output

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to still keep all rows in a summarise output even when one of the columns does not exist. I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,2,3),
                  seq_num=c(0:1,0:2,0:0),
                  time=c(4,5,6,7,8,9))
```

I then need to summarize by all `id`s, where `id` is a row and there is a column for the first `seq_num` and second one. Even if the second one doesn't exist, I'd still like that row to be maintained, with an  `NA` in that slot. I've tried the answers in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523131/dplyr-summarise-equivalent-of-drop-false-to-keep-groups-with-zero-length-in), but they are not working.

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(id, .drop=FALSE) %>% 
  summarise(seq_0_time = time[seq_num==0],
            seq_1_time = time[seq_num==1])
```

outputs

```
     id seq_0_time seq_1_time
  <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1          4          5
2     2          6          7
```

I would still like a 3rd row, though, with `seq_0_time`=9, and `seq_1_time`=`NA` since it doesn't exist.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are only max one observation per 'seq_num' for each 'id', then it is possible to coerce to `NA` where there are no cases with `[1]`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(seq_0_time = time[seq_num ==0][1],
            seq_1_time = time[seq_num == 1][1], .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
     id seq_0_time seq_1_time
  <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1          4          5
2     2          6          7
3     3          9         NA
```

It is just that the length of 0 can be modified to length 1 by assigning NA Or similarly this can be used to replicate NA to fill for 2, 3, etc, by specifying the index that didn't occur

```
> with(dat, time[seq_num==1 & id == 3])
numeric(0)
> with(dat, time[seq_num==1 & id == 3][1])
[1] NA
> numeric(0)
numeric(0)
> numeric(0)[1]
[1] NA
> numeric(0)[1:2]
[1] NA NA
```

Or using `length<-`

```
> `length<-`(numeric(0), 3)
[1] NA NA NA
```

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that you must use `complete()` on both the `seq_num` and `id` variables to achieve your desired result:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,2,3),
                  seq_num=c(0:1,0:2,0:0),
                  time=c(4,5,6,7,8,9)) %>%
  complete(seq_num = seq_num,
           id = id)
dat %>% 
  group_by(id, .drop=FALSE) %>% 
  summarise(seq_0_time = time[seq_num==0],
            seq_1_time = time[seq_num==1])
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      id seq_0_time seq_1_time
#>   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     1          4          5
#> 2     2          6          7
#> 3     3          9         NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I’m not sure I follow. I don’t want to modify the original data. And the data frame would get very sparse because some sequences are 1 unit, while others might be 50.

Comment: the original dataset doesn't contain all combinations of `id` and `seq_num`, so that's why you're missing that last row. You need to have all combinations present (maybe in a new dataframe, so that the original isn't modified) so that you can get the result you've asked for. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question though? Could you rephrase more explicitly then?

Answer (score -1):

This can actually be pretty easily solved using `reshape`.

```
> reshape(dat, timevar='seq_num', idvar = 'id', direction = 'wide')
  id time.0 time.1 time.2
1  1      4      5     NA
3  2      6      7      8
6  3      9     NA     NA
```

Comment: if you're going in this direction, you could also use pivot_wider() to achieve the same effect